# AWS API Gateway + Swagger + Oauth

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, swagger, okta, api-gateway

I am trying to create a new API using

- AWS API Gateway (backed by an AWS Lambda)
- Swagger UI
- Authentication (OAUTH2 with Okta)

I can create a new service with Pythong + Flask + Swagger and host a docker container, which I can develop, but I'm trying to keep it serverless and use the combination of technologies in my list above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might check out JHipster (www.JHipster.tech) for the OAuth + Swagger part. If you generate an app with it, it includes Swagger by default. It also has support for OAuth / OIDC and has been tested with Keycloak and Okta.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to know more about the OAuth part using Okta. You'll have to create a Lambda authorizer that will perform the introspection of the token from Okta.

For the serverless API, you'll have to break your service into functions. An approach is to have one function for each RESTful resource+method:

```
GET /books/{id} -> getBookFunction
PUT /books/{id} -> updateBookFunction
DELETE /books/{id} -> deleteBookFunction
```

Lastly, if you have a well-defined Swagger file. You can use it to create your API in API Gateway. You may also use `x-amazon-apigateway-*` in your Swagger file and define your resource backend to refer to a Lambda function's ARN. Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right, the question is more around how to integrate Oauth2 (Okta) with a swagger UI using AWS API Gateway.

API Gateway 2.0 already provide the ability to inspect the JWT token from Okta, so no need to create a custom Lambda there.

I'm not sure how to get this ability with redirects configured in a Swagger UI, and have the user login using the implicit/authorization-code Grant-Type and let the user interact with the swagger page.